# Multiple xib for defining a page?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib

I'm implementing a lock-screen page in iOS.

But the design for iPhone 6 requires text on top is pretty large, which causes the bottom in the page is hidden in devices equipped with small resolution screen like iPhone 4.

Do I have to define multiple xib for each device in this situation?
Or make some views smaller programmatically?
Or make some margins smaller programmatically?

Are there any references for this? I'm new to auto-layout.

Comment: What is "a lock-screen page"?

Comment: It's a page for in-app screen lock.

Comment: You should manage view's size programmatically from code side so it can be easy for you and also managed for all screens as per your requirement

Comment: autolayouts is the tool for this problem, it will help you not need different xibs, so if you haven't added any yet, you'll have to play around with that. should watch some wwdc vids or just google some tutorials on autolayouts

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use autolayouts. From my understanding your app can be implemented with stack views.
So start with this document,
http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/
and
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-auto-layout-basics--cms-25520

Then checkout the apple documentation for further understanding
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

If the constraints are too confusing, try stack views
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutWithoutConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH8-SW1

Creating multiple xibs is not a solution. Make use of autolayouts :)